# Why didn't Kryptonians have superpowers on Krypton?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015, krypton

Kara's mum told Kara that she would get superpower under Earth's yellow sun. Also, when Supergirl's powers stopped working, D.E.O. tried to recharge her cells with simulated yellow sun light. It was mentioned several times that Superman does the same whenever he loses his powers. These facts say two things:

- Kryptonians didn't have superpowers on Krypton.
- Star's color does matter in the canon.

Now, the color of Krypton's Sun: I know that lots of other canons show Krypton's sun red, but I noticed that Krypton's sun was yellow in *Supergirl (2015)*. Look at the scene which is in my mind:

[image: Kid Kara on Krypton]

What's the catch here? What's the meaning of yellow here if it's not visible yellow color? Any words from writers or producers? Did they forget the facts to show the futuristic city view of Krypton?

Comment: Maybe the title of this Question ought to be "Why is Krypton's sun yellow in Supergirl(2015)?"

Comment: @Beta If a canon doesn't want to use color of star to give someone superpowers (like old comics), then Krypton's sun being yellow won't be a big deal. It's not some kind of universal rule that Krypton can only have red Sun. Unlike Star Wars, Krypton things are canon dependent. There's no central body to control it. So, current title is fine.

Comment: @SS-3 - That is not correct.  DC (the publisher of Supergirl) and WB (their parent company) does provide Kryptonian canon details. Furthermore it's stated, within the Supergirl series, that her powers come from the yellow sun like her cousin (perhaps you should re-watch the series and you will see that while it's not overt it is made clear that her powers are in sync with the DC canon).  Perhaps this will help: http://supergirl.wikia.com/wiki/Kara_Danvers

Comment: BTW, Initial comics didn't have yellow sun thing and there are countless canons showing Superman and Supergirl. And, the copyright has been released in public domain, so anyone can launch story based on them.

Comment: 1. Could be a view screen made to look like a window. 2. If a window it could have filters embedded to make it look yellow. 3. Someone could have screwed up and accidentally made the sun yellow instead of red in the production.

Comment: @Broklynite Great. Convert it into answer. If someone doesn't give a canon answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SS-3: I read your question and I'd stand by Fza's comment, if I were they. Perhaps you should read up on the power-set of Supergirl before you ask such a poor question - It may be time to suspend your disbelief. Is visible light through whatever screen is between the sun & the room so very important?! With the rich history available to pull from you might find your answer is there, it may just be the producers used Pre-Crisis 'ultra solar rays' as her active ingredient. Canonically Kryptonian don't have superpowers on their own planet, so enjoy the show or at least nitpick elsewhere.

Comment: @Hikaru Your comment is also irrelevant to the context. I won't say more.

Answer (score 2):

1. Could be a view screen made to look like a window. 2. If a window it could have filters embedded to make it look yellow. 3. Someone could have screwed up and accidentally made the sun yellow instead of red in the production.

1 and 2 aren't entirely unreasonable. I should preface by saying I don't watch this show and I am not a Kryptonian historian. However, the image of Krypton in the comics has changed over the years, with an increased depiction of the society as having long since become decadent to the point of unmanageability. Simultaneously, they are depicted as having super advanced science going hand in hand with that decadence. This is particularly explored in Last Son of Earth, an admittedly Elseworlds comic where Pa Kent is a scientist who determines that the Earth will explode and builds a rocket to send his son Clark to Krypton, where the atmosphere and increased gravity make Clark uniquely weakened compared to everybody around him.

So it isn't entirely unbelievable to posit that 1 a Kryptonian might live in effectively a sealed capsule existence given space limitations and use view screens that appear to the naked eye to be windows, and/or 2 that perhaps a new fad is to depict a distorted form of reality with changes to things like the color of the sun. Perhaps it is meant as an artistic statement on Krypton, in a society of such decadence that artistic fashion becomes a significant social force.

Or perhaps Kryptonians suffer from an equivalent of Seasonal Mood Disorder, except that they notice that when exposed to yellow sunlight they feel uplifted, but know how damaging to their society it would be for everyone to actually be super powered.

But I suspect that the real reason is number 3, that someone screwed up during production of the episode in question. If you do see the sun frequently and it is always shown as red, then it's likely a screw up. However, if we usually see the sun as yellow, then the take-away is likely that they have decided that the powers no longer come from the color of the sun. Perhaps a la the latest Superman film where it is the atmosphere which somehow imbues a Kryptonian with super powers.

Edit: I must be losing my mind, I thought the question was worded a little bit differently. So, to address why Kryptonians don't have powers on their own planet:

The reasons behind the Kryptonian powers differ from year to year to writer to writer. Fundamentally, they boil down to:

1. Krypton has a set of distinct environmental conditions, as does every planet. Sometimes they are shown as unusually harsh in some fashion or another. The point is that the Kryptonians evolved and developed on the planet along with those conditions, so to them, those conditions are normal.
2. The conditions on earth are different. This might be the lower gravity, the color of the sun, the "air" (sorry, I loathe the last Superman movie) or some other reason. Those three have all been used canonically, however, so make of it what you will.

Going off topic here slightly, but what would actually make a lot of sense that I don't think I have ever seen would be that Krypton was rich in silver kryptonite. As memory serves, Silver is the one which temporarily removes a Kryptonians powers but doesn't otherwise harm them (if I am mixing up the colors, please feel free to correct me). If they all live in a Kryptonite-rich environment, then they may simply have never known that they had powers. Maybe the Kryptonians always had powers but they were suppressed. Maybe Krypton exploding didn't create Kryptonite, but the enormous heat and pressure and energy of the explosion changed the Kryptonite already present to new forms.

Alternately, gold kryptonite may have been present, since later stories sometimes have Kal El sent to earth while still a fetus, and perhaps having escaped as only a few cells allowed it to develop without the influence of gold kryptonite.

Comment: There WAS no Kryptonite on Krypton - Kryptonite was formed by the explosion of the planet, the radiation transmuting it.  Jewel Kryptonite was formed from the jewel mountains , the vast majorty of the planet former green K.  In the comics, Silver K was a hoax, it was artificially created on Smallville, and has not been mentioned in the DCTVU yet, AFAIK.

Comment: Interestingly, for a brief time in the Golden Age, Kryptonians DID have (some) powers on Krypton - in an early version of the origin, Jor-El mentions Earth as a possible escape route. The science council laughs about the planet's people being so backward, "They do not even possess x-ray vision!"

Comment: @VBartilucci the whole silver kryptonite idea was more me idly musing than anything.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 aren't entirely unreasonable. I should preface by saying I don't watch this show and I am not a Kryptonian historian. However, the image of Krypton in the comics has changed over the years, with an increased depiction of the society as having long since become decadent to the point of unmanageability. Simultaneously, they are depicted as having super advanced science going hand in hand with that decadence. This is particularly explored in Last Son of Earth, an admittedly Else worlds comic where Pa Kent is a scientist who determines that the Earth will explode and builds a rocket to send his son Clark to Krypton, where the atmosphere and increased gravity make Clark uniquely weakened compared to everybody around him.Krypton has a set of distinct environmental conditions, as does every planet. Sometimes they are shown as unusually harsh in some fashion or another. The point is that the Kryptonians evolved and developed on the planet along with those conditions, so to them, those conditions are normal.
The conditions on earth are different. This might be the lower gravity, the color of the sun, the "air" (sorry, I loathe the last Superman movie) or some other reason. Those three have all been used canonically, however, so make of it what you will.

Comment: Is that a comment to the other answer?